# How to calculate Spatial Autocorrelation of grouped points in ArcMap 10.2.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, point, spatial-statistics, autocorrelation

I have 32 points uniformly distributed with 7 attributes that comprises continuous values. I used the Grouping Analysis tool in ArcMap 10.2.2. I set 2 groups that have clear differences and are also proposed as best number of groups by the tool.
I also didn't use spatial constraints on purpose.

My goal is to show that the pattern of those grouped points isn't random. In other words, I'd like to apply something like Incremental Spatial Autocorrelation (global Moran's I) tool on the grouped points... I searched in here, but didn't come up with something definite.

Notably, I applied global Moran's I on the grouped points using the "SS GROUP" attribute as an Input Field, both with and withoute row standardization. The results showed no errors, as well as positive but weak autocorrelation.

Comment: So, what is exactly the question here? It seems you have already done it. I think yours is a valid approach. As a validation or added value, you could also run the Moran's with every one of your 7 attributes and see what happens, you would see which attributes are more "location-dependent".

Comment: I think that global Moran's I works only for continuous data. The information that is contained in the Grouping Analysis' attribute named "SS GROUP" isn't continuous.

Apart from that, you mean that I should run the Moran's I for every attribute with the points of each group selected separately? For example: 
Group's 1 points selected -> Moran's I for attribute 1
Group's 1 points selected -> Moran's I for attribute 2... etc
and then Group's 2 points selected -> Moran's I for attribute 1... etc

Comment: And eventually you think that in that way I' ll see which attribute is sort of autocorrelated more and decide about what kind of physical process generated the groups?